# Just like post increment do we have a post assignment in java?

Tags: java

I wish to change(assign) the value of an element at an index in an array:

```
a=array[index];
array[index]=0;
```

Can this be done in one line, like a post/pre increment?

Comment: That's unnecessarily ugly code. You'd probably better off doing two separate statements.

Comment: Can you provide some more clarification on your question? Seems unclear to me

Comment: array[index] = 0 & (a=array[index]); //but don't do that ...

Comment: How will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by calling this

```
int[] array = {0,0,0};
```

Comment: how does this answer the question

Comment: Judging by his example he is looking to instantiate an array.

Comment: The OP is pretty clear that they want to "change(assign) the value of **an element at an index** in an array"...

Answer (score 1):

Based from your question, you want to assign the value from the array and put it on a different variable. and then you want to assign something into it in just one line of code.

```
//I'm assuming that both array and variable a is initialized
array[index] = a + -array[index] + (a = array[index]);
```